# Why is this Android Studio error happening? and How can I solve it?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, uiimageasset

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyQK3.png)

I created 2 image assets, *ic_home* and *ic_profile* in drawable, however, *ic_profile* keeps giving me error when I try to use it.

Anyone know what did I did wrong? help me please.

Comment: Sync your project with gradles files then try cleaning your project by going in build -≥ clean project

Comment: Can tell me a little bit about why this happen please? Just curious, no pressure, I really want to learn more. X)

Answer (score 0):

Sync your project with gradles files then clean your project by going in build -≥ clean project,

Sometimes Android studio mess around and make internal conflicts or errors while resolving references.
When you have errors with dependencies or with symbols that cant resolve even when you made the import you can clean project. Android will then clean all temporary files and recompiles dependencies.
If you still have errors you can rebuild project or go files -≥ invalide cache / restart to make a hard clean